# Android Realm: Primary key constraint broken. Value already exists: 0

Tags: android, primary-key, zero, realm

I'm working a lot with Realm nowadays. I like it a lot! But one thing that's really annoying is that I cannot set my primary key to zero when using copyToRealmOrUpdate. I get my id back from a server. The first id is zero. So my app immediately crashes saying: `Primary key constraint broken. Value already exists: 0`. If this would be a different number than it works just fine, but it crashes on zero. Is this a bug or can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Christian from Realm here. 0 is a bit problematic because it is also the default value for integers. Meaning that if you do have 0 as an actual value, you will run into problems using API's like `Realm.createObject()`. That said, we just fixed a bug using `Realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate()` that covers you exact use case: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/995

It has already been merged to master so should be part of our -SNAPSHOT release, but hasn't been properly released yet. You can try it using:

```
 repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
        }
    }

    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.80.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

Comment: The snapshot indeed solved my issue! Do you have any idea when the proper release will be there?

Comment: We havn't set anything in stone, but most likely this week or the next.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior, Hi Chris, I had the same issue, but instead 0 I see different values, all my items has xxxx digits, in the first run of app I see exception with "Values already exists: xxxx"

Comment: It would probably be easier to create a GitHub issue as that will make debugging easier: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues